# Error with suppressing icon in Windows tray area on Notification message via wxWidgets

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I have a C++ wxWidgets application wherein I am trying suppress the additional icon that pops up in the tray area when I need to display a notification (toast) message to the user.

To do this, I need to call [wxNotificationMessage::MSWUseToasts](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_notification_message.html#a52c56483b083d771de4d0819f4795242) which under Windows 10 will suppress that icon.

The parameters to that function call are a shortcut file path and the application user model id.

Looking at the implementation of how wxWidgets does Toast Notification, the shortcut will have the `lnk` extension added as well the absolute path added to it. So for the parameter I am merely passing the application name as a string.

For the second parameter, as per Microsoft's [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/appids), it is like so "MyCompany.MyApp".

This function returns a `bool` which returns `false` when called with two parameters. But if I call the function with one parameter, it returns `true`. The error below happens with both cases.

I am using Inno Setup to install my application and I am setting the AppUserModelID:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; AppUserModelID: "MyCompany.MyApp"
Name: "{autodesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; AppUserModelID: "MyCompany.MyApp"
```

Thus when I call the method `MSWUseToasts` everything works as expected, but when I close my application I'm basically getting a COM pointer exception, specifically from wxWidgets `wxCOMPtr`. The exception is:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
wxToastNotifMsgImpl::ms_toastMgr.m_ptr->**** was 0x78F253C0. occurred
```

Visual Studio breaks on the error in the file `comptr.h` here:

```
void reset(T* ptr = NULL)
{
    if ( m_ptr != ptr)
    {
        if ( ptr )
            ptr->AddRef();
        if ( m_ptr )
            m_ptr->Release(); // error occurs here
        m_ptr = ptr;
    }
}
```

I don't know enough about COM nor how the toast notifications work behind the scenes which are abstracted away by wxWidgets to know what the exact issue is.

Addendum:

With some Googling, I did find this from an existing [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27977668/7277716). I used the last link posted in the answer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/appmodel/nf-appmodel-getapplicationusermodelid?redirectedfrom=MSDN) where I copy-pasted the code posted at the end of the document into a executable and ran it against the PID of application and for my process it returns `APPMODEL_ERROR_NO_APPLICATION` which means `The process has no application identity.` Not sure if that might correlate to my issue. Googling that error only yields results for issues relating to "no package identity"

Comment: It looks like there is a ref counting bug somewhere in wx code. As usual, the best thing to do would be to try to modify `samples/dialogs/dialogs.cpp` (which already uses `wxNotificationMessage::MSWUseToasts()`) to reproduce the problem and then open a ticket in [wxTrac](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket).

Comment: Thank you @VZ, will try to modify it to replicate the problem